# Git error on push

Tags: git, github

So I'm trying to push a file to GitHub and I'm getting this error:

```
sh-3.2# git push -u origin master
SecGenericPasswordCreate failed
Enter passphrase for key '/var/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Connection closed by 207.97.227.239
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have already setup a public key... but when I try to push, I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following things:

1. Do you really have permission to push (if the repository is not read only)
2. Do you really copied the right public key to the server, there is no unnecessary spaces or newlines

Comment: Well on my mac I'm on this path: `/Users/~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User` I guess here is the problem...or? I did an SSH test to github and It worked...I guess the current location is the problem

Comment: Yeah this was the problem..I copied it to my Desktop and it worked.Thanks a lot